# How to manually update RKHUNTER with newly found rootkits?

Tags: rkhunter

How to manually update RKHUNTER with newly found rootkits?
For example, the current latest version of **rkhunter** tool doesn't detect jynx2 rootkit.
How to manually update it's database. Simple **rkhunter --update** command doesn't work in this case.